# $c_0, \ell^1,\ell^\infty$ and their Dual Spaces: Rudin's RCA, Problem $5.9$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

**Problem $5.9$**, Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

> Let $c_0$, $\ell^1$, and $\ell^\infty$ be the Banach spaces consisting of all complex sequences $x = \{\xi_i\}$, $i = 1,2,3,\ldots$, defined as follows:
> $$x\in \ell^1 \text{ if and only if } \|x\|_1 = \sum |\xi_i| < \infty.$$
> $$x\in \ell^\infty \text{ if and only if } \|x\|_\infty = \sup|\xi_i| < \infty.$$
> $c_0$ is the subspace of $\ell^\infty$ consisting of all $x\in \ell^\infty$ for which $\xi_i \to 0$ as $i\to\infty$. Prove the following four statements:
>
> 1. If $y = \{\eta_i\} \in \ell^1$, and $\Lambda x = \sum \xi_i \eta_i$ for every $x\in c_0$, then $\Lambda$ is a bounded linear functional on $c_0$, and $\|\Lambda\| = \|y\|_1$. Moreover, every $\Lambda\in (c_0)^*$ is obtained in this way. In brief, $(c_0)^* = \ell^1$. (More precisely, these two spaces are not equal; the preceding statement exhibits an isometric vector space isomorphism between them.)
> 2. In the same sense, $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$.
> 3. Every $y\in \ell^1$ induces a bounded linear functional on $\ell^\infty$, as in $(a)$. However, this does not give all of $(\ell^\infty)^*$, since $(\ell^\infty)^*$ contains nontrivial functionals that vanish on all of $c_0$.
> 4. $c_0$ and $\ell^1$ are separable, but $\ell^\infty$ is not.

---

**My work:**

1. I have shown that $\|\Lambda\| = \|y\|_1$. It remains to show that there is an isomorphism between $(c_0)^*$ and $\ell^1$. $\|\Lambda\| = \|y\|_1$ tells us that the map $T: y\mapsto \Lambda$ from $\ell^1$ to $(c_0)^*$ is an isometry, hence it is injective. How do I show that it is also **surjective**? $\color{blue}{\text{Update: Done.}}$
2. I start with similar construction as in the previous part. Consider $T: y\mapsto \Lambda$ such that if $y = \{\eta_i\} \in \ell^\infty$, then $\Lambda x = \sum \xi_i \eta_i$ for every $x\in \ell^1$. Linearity of $\Lambda$ is clear, and for boundedness I get $\|\Lambda\| \le \sup_i |\eta_i|$. I haven't yet been able to show that $\|\Lambda\| = \sup_i |\eta_i|$. Once this is done, injectivity is once again established as earlier, and the surjectivity bit remains. $\color{blue}{\text{Update: Done.}}$
3. $\color{blue}{\text{Update: Done.}}$ (Thanks to the accepted answer.)
4. $\color{blue}{\text{Update: Done.}}$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: (4) The subsets if $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable. If $A,B\subset\mathbb{N}$ and $A\neq B$, then $\|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B\|_\infty=1$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for the comment. That appears later as Theorem $6.16$, which proves that $L^q(\mu)$ is isometrically isomorphic to the dual space of $L^p(\mu)$, for $1 \le p < \infty$. I agree, that immediately gives $(\ell^1)^* = \ell^\infty$ after taking $\mu$ as the counting measure on $\mathbb N$. Very nice observation!

Comment: (1)  Given $L\in c^*_0$, let $\gamma_n=L(\mathbf{e}_n)$. For $f\in c_0$ define $f_n=\sum^n_{k=1} f(k)\mathbf{e}_k$. Show that $\|f_n-f\|_\infty\rightarrow0$. Then, notice that $L(f)=\sum_n\gamma_nf(n)$

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: The collection of rational finite linear combinations of the $\mathbf{e}_n$ defined by OliverDiaz is a countable dense set in both $\mathcal{c}_0$ and $\ell_1$ (or any $\ell_p$ with $0<p<\infty$ for that matter)

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: A proof that $(\mathcal{c}_0)^*$ and $\ell_1$ are isometrically isomorphic is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4196070/809021)

Comment: @JeanL. Does it follow the same approach as followed in the problem above (where only proving surjectivity remains for me)? In any case, I'll read it and let you know.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: it does prove subjectivity. Notice that it gives an $ll_1$ representative for any functional in $(\mathcal{c}_0)^*$.

Comment: For number 3, look up *Banach Limits*

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: FYI, the dual of $L_\infty$ (under $\sigma$-finiteness, is the collection of finitely additive charges of finite variation. Charges are similar to measures, but they are only finitely additive. A good place to look at this is Roko Alipranti's Hitchike guide to infinite analysis. There are specialize papers and even books on charges but fo your purposes, Roko's guide will be more than enough,

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: Do you still have questions on part (3) of your posting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of (3) is just an application of Holder's inequality:

If $f\in\ell_1$, define  $\Lambda_f:\ell_\infty\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as $\Lambda_f x=\sum_n f(n)x(n)$. Clearly $f\mapsto\Lambda_f$ is linear, and $\Lambda_f$ is linear on $\ell_\infty$. By Hölders's inequality
$$|\Lambda_f x|\leq\|f\|_1\|x\|_\infty$$
and so, $\Lambda_f\in\ell_1$. Furthermore, by taking $x\in\ell_\infty$ such that $x(n)f(n)=|f(n)|$ and $|x(n)|=1$, we have that $\|\Lambda_f\|=\|f\|_1$.

For the last part, consider the subspace $\mathcal{c}\subset\ell_\infty$ of sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ that are convergent, and define $\Lambda:\mathcal{c}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ as $\Lambda x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x(n)$. This is a linear functional and clearly
$|\Lambda x|\leq\|x\|$. In fact, by taking $x\equiv1$, we get that $\|\Lambda\|_{\mathbf{c}}=1$. An application of the Hahn-Banach theorem (see Theorem 5.16 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd edition) shows that $\Lambda$ can be extended to all of $\ell_\infty$ as a bounded linear functional so that $\|\Lambda\|=1$. Thus $\Lambda\in(\ell_\infty)^*$. It is not difficult to see that $\Lambda$ has no representation as an element of $\ell_1$, that is, for no $f\in\ell_1$ is $\Lambda=\Lambda_f$.

---

**Comment:** The use of the Hahn Banach theorem seems inevitable. See this [posting](https://mathoverflow.net/q/22661/78591) and links

Comment: The answer looks great. I'm still trying to prove that there is no $f\in \ell^1$ for which $\Lambda = \Lambda_f$. Suppose such an $f\in \ell^1$ exists, to get a contradiction. Since $\Lambda_f$ is a functional on $\ell^\infty$, and $c \subset \ell^\infty$, I think when you say $\Lambda = \Lambda_f$, we are really considering the **restriction** of $\Lambda_f$ to $c \subset\ell^\infty$. We would get $$\Lambda_f x = \sum_n f(n) x(n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} x(n) = \Lambda x \quad (x\in c)$$ How do we find a contradiction?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: yes, those pesky typos... I just fixed it. The most interesting part of this problem is that this types of examples can only be realize with the help of Hand-Banach's theorem, which is a weak version (in a way) of the axiom of choice.

Comment: The Hahn Banach Theorem is a weak version of AOC? I won't be able to sleep tonight. I'm curious.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: that is easy. Suppose there is, that is $\Lambda=\Lambda_f$.  Ask yourself, what is $\Lambda \mathbf{e}_j$? and what is $\Lambda_f\mathbf{e}_j$ (where $\mathbf{e}_j$ is in my previous comments.

Comment: Just take a look at the link that I sent. There is an answer by GEdgard that gives a short overview of the fact. TO get into all the details is to go into the gusts of Set Theory and, unless you want to pursue research in Logic, just known the fact is enough. Later on, if you ever study Logic and Set theory, you can take a look at those things,

Comment: Interesting. If we consider $e_j$ for $j\in \mathbb N$, we would get $f(j) = 0$ for every $j$. So, $f = 0$. This is a contradiction, because in general, for $x\in c$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x(n) \ne 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor: Yes, that is basically the end of the story. One can actually show that the extension $\Lambda$ can be taken to be nonnegatoive, that is $\Lambda x\geq0$ if $x\in\ell^+_\infty$. There is a big theorem that gives a general answer due to Kantorovich. A more elementary treatment for this fact (positivity) can be found in Conway's book on functional analysis (under Banach limits)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning part 3 (following what's mentioned in the comments), the form of the question indicates that you can use Hahn--Banach somewhere.  Think of extending a function which is $0$ on $c_0$ and is bounded above by the functional $\limsup_n x$ (which is sublinear).