# Definition of the spaces $c_{00}$ and $c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, definition

I am given the following chain of subspaces:

Let $S$ be a set. Then we have $c_{00}(S)\subseteq\ell^1(S)\subset c_0(S)\subset \ell^\infty(S)$.
The context is reflexivity and the following theorem is proven:

> There is an isometric isomorphism $\Phi:\ell^1(S)\to c_0(S)^\ast$ given by $\Phi(f)(g)=\sum_{s\in S} f(s)g(s)$ for all $f\in\ell^1(S)$ and $g\in c_0(S)$.

I have tried to find the notation in several books on functional analysis.
$c_0(S)$ seems to be the set of sequences converging to $0$.

And $c_{00}(S)$ should be the set of convergent sequences.

Can you confirm this, or give a reference?
I have also looked at this question: [$c_0, \ell^1,\ell^\infty$ and their Dual Spaces: Rudin's RCA, Problem $5.9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4195762/c-0-ell1-ell-infty-and-their-dual-spaces-rudins-rca-problem-5-9)

And tried to find the notation in Rudin's Book, but it is not listed in the symbol reference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly not every convergent sequence converges to zero, so $c_{00}(S)\subset c_0(S)$ is not compatible with the definition. Usually, the symbol $c$ is used for the Banach space of convergent sequences.

Comment: $c_{00}(S)$ is probably the space of sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms (your guess would not be a subspace of $\ell^1(S)$).

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. @uniquesolution Yes, actually this is not what I meant, my fingers were faster then my brain again.

Comment: I meant $c_{00}(S)$ the set of bounded sequences, not convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you might need *more structure* on the set $S$. It would be nice if $S$ were a normed-linear space, and nicer if it were Banach. For the time being, allow me to assume that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on $S$.

1. $c_{00}(S)$ refers to the space of sequences with finitely many non-zero terms. In other words, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{00}(S)$, then there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n = 0$ for all $n\ge N$.
2. $c_{0}(S)$ refers to the space of sequences that converge to zero. That is, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{0}(S)$, then $x_n \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$ in the topology induced by the norm on $S$.
3. $\ell^1(S)$ consists of sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset S$ satisfying $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|x_n\| < \infty$$
4. Lastly, $\ell^\infty(S)$ consists of sequences $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset S$ satisfying
   $$\sup_{n\ge 1} \|x_n\| < \infty$$

---

*Exercise.* Suppose $S = \mathbb C$ with the usual norm. Can you see which inclusions are *strict*?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will think about your exercise, but will ask a seperate question then.

Comment: Sure! We can also discuss it here itself (in the comments) if you wish. Feel free to ping me if you need any help.