# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \vert f_k\vert < \infty$ and $\Vert f\Vert = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \vert f_k\vert$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The space $c_{0}$ is defined as the space of sequences converging to zero, with the norm $\Vert x \Vert = \sup_{k\geq 1}\vert x_{k} \vert$. For each $f \in c_{0}^*$, we define a sequence $\left( f_{1},\, f_{2},\, \dots \right)$ where $f_k = f(e_k)$:

$e_{k} = \left( 0,\, \dots,\, 0,\, 1,\, 0,\, 0,\, ... \right)$ ($1$ in $k$ position)

Prove that $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\vert f_{k} \vert < \infty$ and $\Vert f \Vert = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\vert f_{k} \vert$. Also show that $c_{0}^* \simeq \ell_1$

My ideas: $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\vert f_{k} \vert \le \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\Vert f_{k} \Vert \Vert e_{k} \Vert = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\Vert f_{k} \Vert \le \sup_{k\geq 1}\vert f_{k} \vert < \infty$ but I'm not sure that's right

Also, $\Vert f \Vert = \sup_{k\geq 1}\vert f_{k} \vert \ge \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\vert f_{k} \vert$ but I don't know how to show $\sup_{k\geq 1}\vert f_{k} \vert \le \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\vert f_{k} \vert$

Also I don't have any ideas about $c_{0}^* \simeq \ell_1$

Comment: Would you tell us what your thoughts are on the task and what you have tried to do so that we can really help you and not just solve the task for you?

Comment: If $f$ is itself a sequence, what is the meaning of $f(e_k)$? It almost sounds like you are claiming that if real numbers tend to zero then their sum is finite, which is false.

Comment: Your "ideas" are weird:
$$|f_k|\le\Vert f_{k} \Vert \Vert e_{k} \Vert?$$ $f_k$ is a number, not a linear form.
$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\Vert f_{k} \Vert \le \sup_{k\geq 1}\vert f_{k} \vert?$$(twice): no.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [A relation between the sequence spaces $c_0$ and $\ell^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815233).